# Is there a site that ranks html tags?

Tags: html, ranking

I'm trying to convince a friend not to use frameset.

Q: Are there statistics along the lines of:

> Of the top x million websites ranked by xyz corporation, x% used
>   frameset.

Comment: Framesets have been removed from HTML5. That alone should be enough to convince 'your friend' not to use them.

Comment: Is there a reason telling him it's deprecated and unsupported doesn't work?

Comment: This one looks interesting: http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/ce-frameset/all/all

Comment: Well, substitute every other html tag for frameset and you'll see what I'm looking for: a way to judge which tags are favored.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are websites that put on a ranking the use of tags, but frames were removed from HTML5. I think that's a good enough reason.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp

Comment: What about the output tag? What if I had a friend that wanted to know how many web pages used the output tag?

Comment: @Phillip I think you should take a look at [help/on-topic], point #4: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Comment: I think it's nearly impossible to get statistics of tag use from ALL pages. What you can do is read about new tech like HTML5, CSS3 and keep up to date with what developers are using.

Comment: Specifically about output tag, it was introduced in HTML5, so it's okay to use it.

Comment: Well, I knew people would say "it's impossible to get statistics of tag use from ALL pages", so that's why I said "x million", but what about every other html tag. For instance, what percentage of x million pages use the italics <i> tag?

Comment: You can calculate a percentage of how many pages uses some tag if you have a limited number of pages to evaluate and knows how many of them uses the tag. But there are millions of pages on the internet. Let's say that 50% of the pages you picked to see if they use the tag, actually uses the tag. Perhaps only 2% of the pages on internet uses the tag. The information you'll get from a few pages is not valid for all pages.

Comment: What if I used http://www.alexa.com/topsites? That would tell me "Of the top 500 (I wish it were more) websites on the Internet, x% use the (fill in the blank) feature.

Comment: Analyse the top websites for the tags they use it's a good way to get what you want. But do that manually it's a lot of work, it would be better if it could be done automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Is there a website that publishes those statistics?

Comment: Here's what I found https://developers.google.com/webmasters/state-of-the-web/2005/ and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11406/recent-statistics-on-html-usage-in-the-wild